# Select a value in a language if in another is empty

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `key_id, id, text, lang`.

I need to retrieve all the text fields (so without limit) in the table in a language (eg. DE), but if in this language the field is empty, I need to retrieve it in English.

Example:

```
key_id, id  text       lang
1       1   hi         en
2       1   Guten Tag  de
3       2   nothing    en
4       2   ''         de
```

I need to have as result, searching with language DE:

**Guten

nothing** -> this is because in deutsch it's empty...

How can I?

Comment: Why don't you just retreive all the languages and choose whatever you want in your program logic?

Comment: can you please be more descriptive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesnt make the table structure completely clear so it is hard to write the Sql for you.  However, I think what you want to do is select both the default(en) value of the word, AND the current(de) version.  It is then a simple matter to supply the chosen value.

```
select ifnull(de.text, en.text)
from
  words de
  join words en on
    en.id = de.id and
    en.lang = 'en'

where de.lang = 'de'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of mysql's non-standard group-by-without-aggregate functionality, which instead of grouping by, it selects the *first* row for each value in the group by. The inner query first orders the data such that the rows are ordered by language preference for each id.

```
select * from (
    select id, text, lang
    from lang_table
    order by id, field(lang, 'de', 'en') -- this provides the custom ordering preference. you can add more languages as you like
) x
group by id; -- this captures the first (preferred language) row for each id
```

Answer (score 0):

first i would have separate table for translations like

[t] id  text

[t_translation] id language text

select coalesce(t_translation.text, t.text) as translated_text 
from t left join t_translation on t.id=t_translation.id where language = 'de'
this way you have fallback if there is no record with 'de' language
(the query is not complete but you get the idea)